# Centos mod_jk works for http but not https

Tags: apache, https, jboss, mod-jk

Using Apache 2.4.6 (Centos 7) + compiled mod_jk 1.2.42 + jboss and following config:
/etc/httpd/conf/worker.properties:

`# Worker Default Values
    worker.default.type=ajp13
    worker.default.socket_keepalive=true
    worker.default.connect_timeout=10000
    worker.default.ping_mode=I
    worker.default.connection_ping_interval=300
    worker.list=sl_jboss-worker
    # Set properties for worker (ajp13)
    worker.sl_jboss-worker.type=ajp13
    worker.sl_jboss-worker.host=centos7.test.pl
    worker.sl_jboss-worker.port=8009`

/etc/httpd/conf.d/zl-jboss.conf:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/worker.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkShmFile /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName centos7.test.pl
    JkMount /* sl_jboss-worker
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName centos7.test.pl
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    JkMount /* sl_jboss-worker
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to use HTTP - the content from jboss server is displayed, if I use HTTPS - then I get 404 error in browser and following error in mod_jk.log

`Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ws_write::mod_jk.c (552): written 3806 out of 3806
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1462): received from ajp13 pos=0 len=2 max=8192
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1462): 0000    05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  - ................
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (2135): (sl_jboss-worker) AJP13 protocol: Reuse is OK
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (851): (sl_jboss-worker) resetting endpoint with socket 18
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3287): recycling connection pool for worker sl_jboss-worker and socket 18
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:11 2018] [4091:139673234200704] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2979): Service finished with status=200 for worker=sl_jboss-worker
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4103:139673234200704] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (679): Attached shared memory /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.4085 [9] size=1024 workers=0 free=0 addr=0x7f0835836000
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4103:139673234200704] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (473): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.4085.lock
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4103:139673234200704] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3478): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.42
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4104:139673234200704] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (679): Attached shared memory /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.4085 [10] size=1024 workers=0 free=0 addr=0x7f0835836000
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4104:139673234200704] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (473): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.4085.lock
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:12 2018] [4104:139673234200704] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3478): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.42
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:17 2018] [4098:139673234200704] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3859): missing uri map for centos7.test.pl:/drm
[Fri Feb 09 19:49:17 2018] [4098:139673234200704] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (4027): missing uri map for centos7.test.pl:/drm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution needed adding

```
JkMountCopy On
```

Into /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, like:

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
JkMountCopy On
```

The sad thing is that this need go here (to _default_ config), and the option JkMountCopy All does not solve it.
Still don't know if its intended behaviour or a bug.